# Swarmplot "gradient"

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, swarmplot

I want to plot a swarmplot like this

[image]

I can highlight the specific point. But I want all the points get kind of the colormap. And the specific point has the respectively color.
I'm trying hue and palette but it does not work.

```
palette = sns.light_palette("purple", reverse=False,  n_colors=df[typeId].max())
ax = sns.swarmplot(x = df[typeId], ax = ax, hue = df[typeId], alpha = 0.8, size = 8)
axData = ax.get_children()
for a in axData:
    if type(a) is matplotlib.collections.PathCollection:
        offsets = a.get_offsets()
        break
ax.scatter(offsets[index,0], offsets[index,1], marker='o', color='red', zorder=10, s=200, edgecolor = "white")
ax.text(offsets[index,0], offsets[index,1]-0.1,"Value: " + str(player[typeId]) + "\nPercentile rank: " + str("{0:.2f}".format(player[typeRank]*100)), ha = "center", color = "white", zorder = 9, fontproperties=prop_bold,fontsize=10)
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the `color` argument to pick a column for color mapping as per the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html).

Comment: @pciunkiewicz I don't really know how it works. Tried color = palette, but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when no `y=` is given, `swarmplot()` doesn't take the `hue=` parameter into account. (And when `y` is a constant, the code seems to hang.)

A workaround is to set the color manually:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

type_ids = np.random.binomial(200, 0.7, 500)
ax = plt.gca()

plt.style.use("dark_background")
ax = sns.swarmplot(x=type_ids, ax=ax, size=8)
for a in ax.get_children():
    if type(a) is matplotlib.collections.PathCollection:
        offsets = a.get_offsets()
        cmap = sns.light_palette("purple", reverse=False, as_cmap=True)
        norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=offsets[:,0].min(), vmax=offsets[:,0].max())
        facecolors = [cmap(norm(x)) for x, y in offsets]
        a.set_color(facecolors)
        break
index = 20
ax.scatter(offsets[index, 0], offsets[index, 1], marker='o', color='red', zorder=10, s=200, edgecolor="white")
ax.text(offsets[index, 0], offsets[index, 1] - 0.1, "\nPercentile rank:  ...",
        ha="center", color="white", zorder=9, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: found a way to do it. But you answered the question, so accepted!

Comment: by the way, do you have any idea about this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969052/plot-another-point-on-top-of-swarmplot

Comment: Would be awesome if you could provide your alternative solution if you solved it in a neat way :) @Chris Maverick

Comment: @cjerik pallete is the way to go

`palette = sns.color_palette("viridis_r", 5)
    ax = sns.swarmplot(ax = ax, x = x, y=y, data=df, alpha = 1, size = 9, palette=palette)`